# ¿Cómo tener obtener el dato de un arreglo que pide el usuario?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

tengo un problema de programación que es el siguiente:

Necesito obtener datos de una API llamada https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users. El metodo que estoy utilizando para obtener los datos es **fetch**.

**Mi código para obtener datos es el siguiente**

```js
const info = document.getElementById("getInfo");
info.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    
    .then((res)=>{console.log(res);
    })
});
```

```html
 <h1>Get User Info</h1>
    <button id="getInfo">Get Info</button>
    <div id="data">
        <h2>Informacion</h2>
    </div>
```

Lo que yo necesito es que haya un *.then()* (dentro del fetch) que tenga una función de flecha ➡ que solcite lo siguiente

```
.then((res) => {
    const getDatos = (dato que necesito Ej. "id" "email", etc.) => {
       Aqui va el codigo
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que recibes un array, simplemente puedes usar [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para filtrar los elementos del array que recibes

```js
const info = document.getElementById("getInfo");
info.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res)=>{
      const resultado = res.filter(e => e.email === "Julianne.OConner@kory.org")[0];
      // El string es el email por buscar
      console.log(resultado);
      // Si se busca por ID, simplemente cambia e.email por e.id
    })
});
```

```html
<h1>Get User Info</h1>
<button id="getInfo">Get Info</button>
<div id="data">
  <h2>Informacion</h2>
</div>
```